# Java substr not working as expected

Tags: java, substring, brainfuck

So I'm making a [brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) interpreter in Java and I don't have any problems with it except for the [ and ]. (Inevitably) The problem is with parsing the string. So what I do to deal with the loop is locate the code in between the two brackets and recall the function (Recursion) to redo the code inside the brackets. This sounds nice on paper but `substring` is not cooperating with me. Here is where I deal with the [

```
void openBracket(short i, String brainfuck)
    {
        /*LOGIC EXPLAINED: First set balance = 1, then loop through all characters after this,
         if another opening bracket is found increment balance, if a close bracket is found, 
         decrement balance. Also, when another close bracket is found test if balance is 1, if
         so then this is the proper bracket*/
        String codeSection = brainfuck.substring(i);
        short balance = 1;
        String codeToRedo;
        short endPoint = -1;

        for (short j = i; j < codeSection.length(); j++) 
        {
        //Check the character
        if (codeSection.charAt(j) == '[') 
        {
            balance++;
        } else if (codeSection.charAt(j) == ']') 
        {
            balance--;

        }
        //Check if it's the right bracket
        if (balance == 1) {
            endPoint = j;
        }
        }

        //Only do such a thing if the cell is not equal to 0
        if (cell[pointer] > 0 && endPoint != -1) 
        {
        codeToRedo = brainfuck.substring(i, endPoint);
        output += brainfuckExecute(codeToRedo);
        } 
        else if (endPoint == -1) //If endpoint is equal to -1, that means that there was no closing bracket
        {
        errorList += "ERROR: No closing bracket (" + i + ")";
        }
    }
```

I apologize about the indenting, it didn't copy very well form Netbeans. But anyways, as you can see at the top of the code, I make a variable called 'codeSection,' and it should contain the proper text. Here is what I give for the argument 'brainfuck': `+++[>+++++ +++++<-]>+++.` Here is what I get when I print the variable:

```
[>+++++ +++++<-]>+++.
[>+++++ +++
```

Yes, I print the variable with System.out.println and I get two different things printed. The first time, it is the correct string. The second time I get what is processed, and that has no closing bracket. I have an error checking system rigged up in the code for brainfuck, so I can check. And I get the error I should. (ERROR: No closing bracket (0))
I am really dazed and confused with this one, so any help provided is greatly appreciated.

P.S. Extra code, like where it's called and such:
Where it's called:

```
String brainfuckExecute(String brainfuck)
    {
        //Reset the output
        output = "";

        //Loop through all instructions
        for(short i = 0; i < brainfuck.length(); i++)
        {
        //Execute a switch to do the instructions
        switch(brainfuck.charAt(i))
        {
            //Increment current cell
            case '+': 
            incrementCell();
            break;
            //Decrement current cell
            case '-': 
            decrementCell(i);
            break;
            //Move pointer up
            case '>': 
            incrementPointer(i);
            break;
            //Move pointer down
            case '<': 
            decrementPointer(i);
            break;
            //Get user input and store it in the current cell
            case ',': 
            getInput();
            break;
            //Add the cell to the output string
            case '.': 
            addOutput();
            break;
            //Start the while loop -- Recurssive
            case '[': 
            openBracket(i, brainfuck);
            break;
        }
        }

        //Return said output
        return output;
    }
```

(It's within a class that has all those variables)
Where main is:

```
Brainfuck codeTranslator = new Brainfuck();
    System.out.println(codeTranslator.brainfuckExecute("+++[>+++++ +++++<-]>+++."));
    System.out.println(codeTranslator.getErrors());
```

Again, thanks

Comment: #1: Read the javadoc on [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) to make sure you have the right idea of how it works.  It often confuses people who are used to substring operations in other languages.  #2: If you're still confused about how `substring` works, please ask a question with a reduced example, e.g. the string, the parameters, what you think it should give you, and what it's really giving you.  I don't want to trace through a bunch of code just to answer a question about `substring`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `openBracket()` for the first time, you have `i == 3` and `brainfuck == "+++[>+++++ +++++<-]>+++."`. So, in the first `substring()` call you get:

```
String codeSection = brainfuck.substring(3);
```

Which results in:

```
String codeSection = "+++[>+++++ +++++<-]>+++.".substring(3);
String codeSection = "[>+++++ +++++<-]>+++."
```

Then you loop through `codeSection` to see if it is balanced. The problem is that you already cut out the part before the `[`, but you begin your loop at `j = 3`. I will mark the current index positions with `( )`, so it is easier to follow:

You start the loop at `j = 3`:

```
[>+(+)+++ +++++<-]>+++.
```

And go until `j = 14`, which is the index of `-` just before `]`:

```
[>+++++ +++++<(-)]>+++.
```

Since you didn't find the first `[`, the value of `balance` was `1` all this time. So, in the end, you did `endPoint = 14`.

```
if (balance == 1) {
    endPoint = j;
}
```

In the next iteration you find the `]`, and `balance` gets decremented to `0`, so the loop keeps going but `endPoint` is not updated again.

After this, you do:

```
codeToRedo = brainfuck.substring(i, endPoint);
```

Which results in:

```
codeToRedo = brainfuck.substring(3, 14);
codeToRedo = "+++[>+++++ +++++<-]>+++.".substring(3, 14);
codeToRedo = "[>+++++ +++";
```

I guess your loop should really be:

```
for (short j = 0; j < codeSection.length(); j++) { ... }
```

And finally, to get only the part of `brainfuck` that's between the brackets you should notice that, while `balance` is 1, you keep updating the value of `endPoint`. I think you want to stop when you find the balancing bracket, so you can add a `break` inside your `if`:

```
for (short j = 0; j < codeSection.length(); j++) {
    //Check the character
    if (codeSection.charAt(j) == '[') {
        balance++;
    } else if (codeSection.charAt(j) == ']') {
        balance--;
    }
    //Check if it's the right bracket
    if (balance == 1) {
        endPoint = j;
        break; // Stop when you find the ] position
    }
}
```

Then do:

```
codeToRedo = brainfuck.substring(i + 1, i + endPoint);
```

Or:

```
codeToRedo = codeSection.substring(1, endPoint);
```

Also, you concatenate the results of `brainfuckExecute()` when you do `output += brainfuckExecute(codeToRedo)`. That's probably why it looks like it is printing twice.

Comment: So I read through it, and I sort of understand. I get the j = i, and I fixed that,  but I'm not fully understanding how to fix the final bracket issue. And why is System.out.println printing twice when it was called once? And where is 14 coming from? (Sorry to pummel you with questions.)

Comment: After adding a few more things it works! Thanks so much for your help!